# Make Json an Angular object

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I ran into little difficulty, came out of a login system for the project I made,
The project is written in JAVA, SPRINGBOOT and linked to ANGULAR
I have a login function on a server that returns a JSON object that looks like this:
{"type": 2, "token": "dab022de 011a 4"}
And for further testing I want to use these two obj in angular after I get them, for example:
If you type = 2, you will see a component that is tailored to you,
If you type = 1, you will see a diffrent component
To do this, I really need to capture the return value from the server into an object, for example:
this.clientType = _________?
Appends some code to make it clearer:

login server side code:

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<LoginInfo> login(@RequestParam String email, @RequestParam String password)
        throws InvalidLoginException {
    ClientSession clientSession = loginSystem.createClientSession(email, password);

if (clientSession == null) {
    throw new InvalidLoginException(
            String.format("Invalid login with email: %s and password: %s .", email, password));
}
String token = generateToken();
clientSession.accessed();
LoginInfo loginfo;
for (Entry<String, ClientSession> entry : tokensMap.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().getAbsService().getClientId() == clientSession.getAbsService().getClientId()
            && entry.getValue().getAbsService().getRole() == clientSession.getAbsService().getRole()) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(loginfo = new LoginInfo(entry.getValue().getAbsService().getRole(), token));
    }
}
tokensMap.put(token, clientSession);
LoginInfo loginInfo = new LoginInfo(clientSession.getAbsService().getRole(), token);
return ResponseEntity.ok(loginInfo);
}
```

login function in typeSqript:

```
login():void {
    let userCredentials = new UserCredentials(this.email, this.password);

    let obsJwt = this.authService.authenticateMe(userCredentials);
    obsJwt.subscribe(myToken=>{
      console.log(myToken);//return  {"type":2,"token":"dab022de 011a 4"} for example
      localStorage.setItem("token",myToken.any); // here i want to put just the token, its not working too...
      this.modeService.mode = this.modeService.LOOGED_IN;

    }, err=>{
      alert("error: " + err.message);
    })
  }
```

In this function I'm not sure about **anything**, I'm pretty new to the angular so if you have any general tips for improvement I would love to hear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what is returning the `authenticateMe` function of `authService`.

Let suppose that returns an object from a class or that implements an interface, something like `Observable<LoginResponse>` where:

```
interface LoginResponse {
  type: number,
  token: string
}
```

If that is the case then you just need to access the properties,

```
obsJwt.subscribe(myToken=>{
  localStorage.setItem("token", myToken.token);
  localStorage.setItem("type", myToken.type);
}, err=>{
  alert("error: " + err.message);
})
```

If for some reason is a string `Observable<string>` in json format then you need to parse it to an object,

```
obsJwt.subscribe(myToken=>{
  const obj = JSON.parse(myToken);
  localStorage.setItem("token", obj.token);
  localStorage.setItem("type", obj.type);
}, err=>{
  alert("error: " + err.message);
})
```

Comment: thanks! i did the parse,
I have another question if you don't mind.
After I login, I want it saved, right now the situation is that after I refresh the page the user logs out of the system(just in the client side)
How can this be improved?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, usually when login you store the credentials and then on logout you remove it from store. When the application start you check for credentials in the store, if there are credentials then your user is logged, if there are no credentials then you redirect the user to your login page. But again it depends on your needs.